# Shower Over Existing Bath

Tags: shower, bathtub

I have an exsiting bathtub with a short shower hose for use when bathing. I want to add a longer hose and a wall attachment so that we can have stand-up showers. I'm curious whether baths with showers are specifically designed to take the weight of a standing person - or if any bath will be fine.

I don't want to run the risk of breaking the bath if it wasn't designed to be stood in. (Unfortunately I don't know the make of the bath but it is fairly new).

Comment: You can confidently assume any tub is designed for a standing person. Is this fiberglass, steel (e.g. Americast) or cast iron porcelain?  What do you mean a short shower hose? One mounted low and designed for a sitting person?

Comment: How much weight is added by filling the bath? :)

Comment: @GrahamChiu Yes I though about that, I just didn't know if bathtubs were reinforced underneath a bit more to take the spot-pressure of a standing person. The bath is a fairly decent fibreglass type.